# How to avoid callback hell in this simple program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1q6Y.png)

this is the full code commented.

```
//program purpose:
//list all directories in a given path.
//choose a file and print wether it's a regular file  or a directory;
fs = require('fs'); //filesystem
const readline = require('readline-sync');// reads input
var dirPath = readline.question("enter directory path.\n>>> ");
//reads directory with dirPath;
fs.readdir(dirPath,(err,files)=>{
  if (err) {
    console.log("Oopps there has been an error. ");
    console.log(err);
  }else {
    //prints files in the directory.
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      console.log(i+")"+files[i]);
    }
    //choose a file.
    var filePath = readline.question("Choose a file.\n>>> ");
    //checks if the choice is a file or directory
    fs.stat(dirPath+filePath,(err,stats)=>{
      if (err) {
        console.log("Oopps there has been an error. ");
        console.log(err);
      }else {
        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
          console.log("its a directory.");
          //if its a file print its content
        }else {
          fs.readFile(dirPath+filePath,'utf-8',(err,data)=>{
            if (err) {
              console.log("Oopps there has been an error. ");
              console.log(err);
            }

            else {
              console.log(data);
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }

});
```

I am trying to get a grip of the asynchronous nature of javascript,i wanted to refactor the code this is it:
[Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sGjW.png)

The problem: the second picture, the readir is interrupted by the filepath input, how can i fix this, i want the code to look nice and be able to use those functions maybe recursively.

Comment: Sorry, i did not comment, because i wanted to get it in one screenshot. should add comment and paste the code instead of a picture?

Comment: Editing the question and including the code as text would be preferrable, yes.

Comment: @ilyeshamrouni Yes please update your question with the code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Also, the answer to your question is most certainly [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Comment: Thanks, this should help.

Comment: http://callbackhell.com/ , this is excatly what i want to do (manually without using the help of a module), however it only gives one example, and i fail to apply that to my code as you can see in Code2

Comment: Use promises instead of plain callbacks. They are supposed to help with callback hell.

Comment: Yes I get it now, thanks I appreciate all the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways and using them you can make it simple.

**Modularization** - Making each callback into an independent function

**Promise** - Holds eventual result of asynchronous operation. As it is object-oriented, you would get fluent interface. Therefore, calling methods by chaining.

**async/await** - It is functional implementation of `Promise`. It works the same way as the `Promise` does.

It these does not work for you can use this library called [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

Comment: Thank you I will dig deeper into these steps and get a hold of it.

Comment: You're very welcome! You should mark the answer as correct. I mean the answer that helped you more. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ES6 generators can eliminate callback hell.
And also allow you to add
program flow like loops,
which I have added to your example to show how easy this is.

I have also added the appropriate `require()` lines, and made `readline.question`
into another asynchronous function so it will run as a complete
example on node.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
function* myGenerator(dirPath) {
    const callback = yield;
    const [err1, files] = yield fs.readdir(dirPath, callback);
    if (err1) {
        console.log("Oopps there has been an error. ");
        console.log(err1);
        return;
    }
    //prints files in the directory.
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        console.log(i + ")" + files[i]);
    }
    //choose a file.
    var filePath;
    while (true) {
        [filePath] = yield readline.question("Choose a file.\n>>> ", callback);
        //checks if the choice is a file or directory
        console.log("aaa", dirPath, "bbb", filePath);
        const[err2, stats] = yield fs.stat(dirPath + filePath, callback);
        if (err2) {
            console.log("Oopps there has been an error. Try again.");
            console.log(err2);
        } else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            console.log("its a directory. Try again");
        } else {
            break; // OK choice
        }
    }
    // it's a file. Print its content
    const [err3, data] = yield fs.readFile(dirPath + filePath, 'utf-8', callback);
    if (err3) {
        console.log("Oopps there has been an error. ");
        console.log(err3);
        return;
    }
    console.log(data);
}

// Create and run the generator
const gen = myGenerator("./"); // Create it
gen.next(); // Start it
gen.next((...args) => gen.next([...args])); // Set its callback function
```

By comparison Promises alone don't let you use loops.
The async/await method has similar benefits to using generators
but it requires that you wrap all your async calls in Promises.
I therefore find that generators are easier.

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped me.